# Cannot read property 'play' of undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-redux, rxjs

Hey guys i am new to react and this error is making me frustrated, even tho the thing is not undefined it keeps saying its undefined, I used useRef()....

```js
import React from "react"
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import firebase from "firebase";
import fire from "./firebase"
import { useHistory } from "react"


function AudioPlayer(props){
    const audioRef = useRef();
    if (props.play === "true"){
        play()
    }
    
    const [progVal, setProgVal] = useState("0%")
    function update(event){
        let duration = (event.target.currentTime/event.target.duration)*100
        setProgVal(duration)
        console.log(progVal)
    }

    function play(){
        const audioPlayer = audioRef.current
        console.log(audioPlayer)
        audioPlayer.play()
        //document.getElementById('player').play()
    }

    function stop(){
        
    }
    return(
            <div className = "audio-wrapper">
                <div className = "audio-container">
                    <div className = "audio-box">
                        <audio id = "player" ref = {audioRef} src = "url" name = "audioplayer" onTimeUpdate = {update}>
                        </audio>
                        <button onClick = {play}>Play</button>
                        <button onClick = {stop}>stop</button>
                        <div class = "progress_div">
                            <div class = "progress_holder" id= "prog_holder">
                                <div id = "progress_meter" style = {{width: progVal + "%"}}></div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    )
}


export default AudioPlayer
```

Any fix, i would really appreciate if you give me solutions.

Comment: Try audioRef?.current or audioPlayer?.play()

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely accessing to the `ref` before it's actually initialized. I would suggest to invoke `play` as your component is mounted.

```js
function AudioPlayer(props) {
  // Only does thing as component got mounted
  useEffect(() => {    
    if (props.play === "true"){
      play()
    }
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: hmm it didnt solve the problem for some reason

Comment: You still did suffer undefined issue, didn't you?

Comment: yes i did, but when i added setTimeOut() function the problem doesnt show up

Comment: Would you try  to add `audioRef` as effect dependency? Then check it before using as: `useEffect(() => { if (audioRef.current) { /* do your job */ } }, [audioRef])`